# Compare if cells between two columns are exactly matched, partially matched and do not match

Tags: sql-server, compare

I have Table 1 below (codes represent responses). I want to compare Columns 2 and 3.

| ID | Code A | Code B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | A,B | B,A |
| 101 | B,D,C | D,C,E |
| 102 | E,A | B,C |

If both columns have an equal number of responses and the responses are the same (regardless of position), then it is an exact match (assigned a value of 1).

If both columns do not have an equal number of responses but some responses are similar between the two columns, then it is a partial match (assigned a value of 2).

If both columns do not have any similar responses, then it is a no match (assigned a value of 3).

So the new table should look like:

| ID | Code A | Code B | Match_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | A,B | B,A | 1 |
| 101 | B,D,C | D,C,E | 2 |
| 102 | E,A | B,C | 3 |

Comment: If you had a normalised design, this would be *significantly* easier. Why not fix your design?

Comment: @Larnu i am very new to ms-sql. thanks. i will have to read on what a normalised design is.

Comment: Normalized design is not specific to ms-sql, it is a method of designing your tables so they can be used in any relational database, and so there is no redundancy of your data